# sentence structure quesiton

Tags: sentence-structure

> In comparing different methods **by which a teacher's performance can
>   be evaluated and educational outcomes improved**, researchers found
>   that a critique of teacher performance leads to enhanced educational
>   outcomes if the critique is accompanied by the information that
>   teacher performance is merely one of several factors that determines
>   the educational outcomes.

I am having hard time understanding the structure of bold part, especially because of the part "outcomes improved". Between "outcomes" and "improved", is there an "can be" hided so it can be paralleled with "performance can be evaluated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a hidden **"can be".**

It would read:

> by which a teacher's performance can be evaluated and their educational outcomes can be improved